# Creating a sub-page in CodeIgniter using URL routing

Tags: php, codeigniter, url-routing

I have a form which is starting to get a bit too complex, so I want to split one page into three different pages. I understand that I need to use URL routing to achieve this, but no luck so far. Reading the manual didn't help.

Current URL is as following:

```
index.php/profiles/edit/$id
```

I want to achieve something like this:

```
index.php/profiles/edit/contact/$id
index.php/profiles/edit/pictures/$id
...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need to do routing. You can simply improve your edit function like this.

```
public function edit($type,$id)
{
    if($type=='contact')
    {
        //do contact task
    }
    if($type=='pictures')
    {
        //do picture task
    }

}
```

Now your expected links will work.